# Non-interactive way to tell web site, that I allow cookies

Tags: http, cookies, rfc

I am wearing the web-browser user hat here. I am a user, not a provider of a web service:

Is there a non-interactive way to tell web site, that I allow cookies?

During the last weeks most web site have a pop up.

I never read any of them, I always clicked on "ok" or "yes".

Is there a way to tell the web site that I allow cookies?

Maybe via http-header or an other way...

Example: Here is the pop-up from nbc.com:

[image: cookie-from-nbc.com]

Comment: This would pretty much defy the purpose of the whole exercise. The law *requires* that the user's consent must be "informed, specific, freely given and must constitute a real indication of the individual's wishes." A blanket "I allow cookies" would at least not be specific. Therefore, in order to comply with the law, the site owner would then have to find a way to *defeat* that mechanism, so that he can ask nonetheless.

Comment: If there is a http-header (sent from client to server in the request) which states "I allow all cookies") then I think there is no need for a manual "ok".

Comment: "I allow all cookies" is very likely not specific enough to comply with the law(s). But, you should consult your lawyer about that.

Comment: @JörgWMittag you say "law". Which law does apply? The law of the country where the server is located. The law of the location of the client. Or United Nation Organization? Or ....

Comment: Any court can accept any case for any reason if they want to. In the EU, for example, data privacy laws apply to EU citizens. So, if I, as a EU citizen, use your service, then I can sue you for any violation of my EU privacy rights. And this includes the fact that for any data you are processing, you need my *specific*, *informed*, *freely given* consent. Freely given means that you cannot tie delivering your service to my consent. If you say, you will only provide your service if I consent to you processing my data, then my consent is not freely given and doesn't count. If you don't tell me …

Comment: … exactly what data you are processing and why, what you do with it, how you protect it, whom you may pass it on to, then my consent is not informed, and doesn't count. If you don't explicitly ask my consent for every new piece of data you process or for every new way you process it, then it is not specific and doesn't count.

Comment: I think this is what you need. - https://cdn.whatismybrowser.com/prod-website/static/main/content/guides/how-to-enable-cookies/chrome-windows-step-06.jpg . Experiment with this. e.g. keep 1) - `On` and 2)3) - `Off`

Comment: What you are describing is "implied consent", which was the standard way to get consent. However as @JörgWMittag has explained, that is no longer allowed within the EU since (**GDPR**) came into effect in May 2018. **So *do not* attempt to do this... penalties for non-compliance are up to €10 MILLION, or 2% annual global turnover - whichever is HIGHER**

Comment: @FluffyKitten If I install a plugin for my browser which some auto-accept this pop-up. Then I am deeply relaxed. I am not afraid. If I had time and knowledge, then I would develop such a plugin. And again, I am deeply relaxed. I don't think that the user or developer of such a plugin gets accused. ... €10 MILLION (I think you must write this in upper-case letters, otherwise 100 € MILLION).... It is different, if you are running the server which wants to store cookies.

Comment: I'm not sure your would-be customers would be impressed with your indifference to your legal obligations.

Comment: @FluffyKitten there are no would-be customers. I updated the question: I am wearing the web-browser user hat here. I am a user, not a provider of a web service.

Comment: Because of 'General Data Protection Regulation' you have to manually click to agree that you accept what they do with your data. You can't just say automatically yes. Do you sign contracts without reading too?

Comment: Is clicking "OK" on the cookie pop-up a contract?

Comment: Again, if there were a way of doing what you want to do, then the owner of the website would be in violation of the GDPR, and could be fined (depending on the severity of the violation) up to 10000000€ or 2% annual global turnover for the entire concern, or even up to 20000000€ / 4% plus prison time for company executives, for serious violations. They *cannot* allow you to do this, because the law requires them to get your *specific, informed, explicit* consent, and robot-clicking is none of the three.

Comment: @JörgWMittag sooner or later browser plugins will be created by clever people who can detect the usual annoying "please click ok for cookies" pop-ups. What should the owners of the websites do? Do you think Captchas would be a good solution?

Answer (score -1):

Almost Every site make users  accept cookies based on browser settings and where they originated from .
You don't have to do anything .It was always non interactive.
check this

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp[image: google cookies]

Most sites are placing cookies.see my screenshot of google.
So any site which has user account creation they want to tell you we are creating cookies and cookies might have username or email or last logged in .
They might be  used by hackers or spyware .
While OS prevents it from happening you cannot read cookies from other site via a web site.
Desktop applications can read
check this 
https://blog.teamtreehouse.com/encrypting-cookies-in-the-browser